Django POST method is not receiving all input fields from HTML template (one HTML form field only)
I am coding a page for course registration. However, when I tried to get the data from the HTML form and receive it through request.POST method in Django, it only took the record for the input tag of choosing which course I wanted to enroll in, and leaving the select field class empty string. I did organize all input fields into one form only. Please help me.
The view of course registration
@login_required
@student_required
def course_registration(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        student = Student.objects.get(student__pk=request.user.id)
        ids = ()
        data = request.POST.copy()
        data.pop("csrfmiddlewaretoken", None)  # remove csrf_token
        # Extract course and class information
        courses_selected = []
        classes_selected = {}
        for key, value in data.items():
            print(f"Processing {key}: {value}")
            if key.startswith("course_"):
                course_id = key.split("_")[1]
                course = Course.objects.get(pk=course_id)
                # Check if a class was selected for this course
                class_key = f"class_{course_id}"
                if class_key in data and data[class_key]:
                    selected_class = Class.objects.get(pk=data[class_key])
                    classes_selected[course_id] = selected_class
                else:
                    classes_selected[course_id] = None

                # Create enrollment record
                if course_id not in courses_selected:
                    courses_selected.append(course_id)
                    Enrollment.objects.create(
                        student=student,
                        course_enrolled=course,
                        class_enrolled=classes_selected[course_id]
                    )

        messages.success(request, "Courses and classes registered successfully!")
        return redirect("course_registration")
    else:
        current_semester = Semester.objects.filter(is_current_semester=True).first()
        if not current_semester:
            messages.error(request, "No active semester found.")
            return render(request, "course/course_registration.html")

        # student = Student.objects.get(student__pk=request.user.id)
        student = get_object_or_404(Student, student__id=request.user.id)
        taken_courses = TakenCourse.objects.filter(student__student__id=request.user.id)
        t = ()
        for i in taken_courses:
            t += (i.course.pk,)

        courses = (
            Course.objects.filter(
                program__pk=student.program.id,
                level=student.level,
                semester=current_semester,
            )
            .exclude(id__in=t)
            .order_by("year")
        )
        # Extract course IDs from the queryset
        course_ids = courses.values_list('id', flat=True)

        # Query all classes related to the courses
        classes = Class.objects.filter(course__in=course_ids)

        all_courses = Course.objects.filter(
            level=student.level, program__pk=student.program.id
        )

        no_course_is_registered = False  # Check if no course is registered
        all_courses_are_registered = False

        registered_courses = Course.objects.filter(level=student.level).filter(id__in=t)
        if (
            registered_courses.count() == 0
        ):  # Check if number of registered courses is 0
            no_course_is_registered = True

        if registered_courses.count() == all_courses.count():
            all_courses_are_registered = True

        total_first_semester_credit = 0
        total_sec_semester_credit = 0
        total_registered_credit = 0
        for i in courses:
            if i.semester == "First":
                total_first_semester_credit += int(i.credit)
            if i.semester == "Second":
                total_sec_semester_credit += int(i.credit)
        for i in registered_courses:
            total_registered_credit += int(i.credit)
        context = {
            "is_calender_on": True,
            "all_courses_are_registered": all_courses_are_registered,
            "no_course_is_registered": no_course_is_registered,
            "current_semester": current_semester,
            "courses": courses,
            "total_first_semester_credit": total_first_semester_credit,
            "total_sec_semester_credit": total_sec_semester_credit,
            "registered_courses": registered_courses,
            "total_registered_credit": total_registered_credit,
            "student": student,
            "classes": classes,
        }
        return render(request, "course/course_registration.html", context)

The HTML template course_registration.html
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}{{ title }} | Learning management system{% endblock title %}
{% load static %}

{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}

<nav style="--bs-breadcrumb-divider: '>';" aria-label="breadcrumb">
    <ol class="breadcrumb">
        <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Course Registration</li>
    </ol>
</nav>

<p class="title-1">Course Add &amp; Drop</p>

{% include 'snippets/messages.html' %}

{% if current_semester %}
{% if is_calender_on == False %}

<div class="alert bg-danger">
    <h1 class="text-light text-center">Calendar is off</h1>
    <h5 class="text-light text-center">Check the university calendar</h5>
</div>

{% else %}

{% if not all_courses_are_registered %}

<form action="{% url 'course_registration' %}" method="POST" id="course_registration" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
{#    {% load custom_filter %}#}
    <div class="col-md-12 p-0 bg-white">
        <p class="form-title fw-bold">Course Add</p>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between mb-3">
                <button title="Save Score" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add Selected
                </button>
            </div>

            <div class="table-responsive p-0 px-2 mt-2">
                <div class="table-title"><u>First Semester:</u></div>
                <div class="table-shadow">
                    <table class="table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Mark</th>
                                <th>Course Code</th>
                                <th>Course Title</th>
                                <th>Cr.Hr(s)</th>
                                <th>Year</th>
                                <th>Classification</th>
                                <th>Elective Group</th>
                                <th>Class</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            {% for course in courses %}
                            {% if course.semester == "First" %}
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row">
                                    <input name="course_{{ course.pk }}" value="{{ course.pk }}" type="checkbox" 
                                           form="course_registration" required>
                                </th>
                                <td>{{ course.code }}</td>
                                <td>{{ course.title }}</td>
                                <td>{{ course.credit }}</td>
                                <td>{{ course.year }}</td>
                                {% if course.is_elective %}
                                <td>Elective</td>
                                {% else %}
                                <td>Core</td>
                                {% endif %}
                                <td>-</td>
                                <td>
                                    <label for="class_{{ course.pk }}"></label>
                                    <select name="class_{{ course.pk }}" id="class_{{ course.pk }}" form="course_registration" required>
                                        <option disabled selected value>Select Class</option>
                                        {% for cls in classes %}
                                            {% if cls.course.id == course.id %}
                                                <option value="{{ cls.id }}">{{ cls }}</option>
                                            {% endif %}
                                        {% endfor %}
                                    </select>
                                <input type="hidden" name="class_{{ course.pk }}_hidden" id="class_{{ course.pk }}_hidden">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            {% endif %}
                            {% empty %}
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td>
                                    <span class="text-danger">No Course.</span>
                                </td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            {% endfor %}
                            <tr>
                                <th></th>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td><b>First semester Credit(s):</b> {{ total_first_semester_credit }} </td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="table-responsive p-0 px-2 mt-2">
                <div class="table-title"><u>Second Semester:</u></div>
                <div class="table-shadow">
                    <table class="table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Mark</th>
                                <th>Course Code</th>
                                <th>Course Title</th>
                                <th>Cr.Hr(s)</th>
                                <th>Year</th>
                                <th>Classification</th>
                                <th>Elective Group</th>
                                <th>Class</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            {% for course in courses %}
                            {% if course.semester == "Second" %}
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row">
                                    <input name="{{ course.pk }}" value="{{ course.courseUnit }}" type="checkbox">
                                </th>
                                <td>{{ course.code }}</td>
                                <td>{{ course.title }}</td>
                                <td>{{ course.credit }}</td>
                                <td>{{ course.year }}</td>
                                {% if course.is_elective %}
                                <td>Elective</td>
                                {% else %}
                                <td>Core</td>
                                {% endif %}
                                <td>-</td>
                                <td>
                                    <select name="class_{{ course.pk }}">
                                        <option value="">Select Class</option>
                                        {% for cls in classes %}
                                            {% if cls.course.id == course.id %}
                                                <option value="{{ cls.id }}">{{ cls }}</option>
                                            {% endif %}
                                        {% endfor %}
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            {% endif %}
                            {% empty %}
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td>
                                    <span class="text-danger">
                                        No Course.
                                    </span>
                                </td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            {% endfor %}
                            <tr>
                                <th></th>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td><b>Second semester credit(s):</b> {{ total_sec_semester_credit }} </td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row"></th>
                                <td><b>Registered course credit(s): <a id="units">{{ total_registered_credit }}</a></b>
                                </td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td><b>Total credit(s):</b> {{ total_sec_semester_credit|add:total_first_semester_credit }} </td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
{% endif %}
<br>
<br>

{% if not no_course_is_registered %}

<a class="btn btn-warning" href="{% url 'course_registration_form' %}" target="_blank" title="Print Registration Form">
    <i class="fas fa-print"></i> Print Registered Courses
</a>

<div class="col-md-12 p-0 bg-white">
    <p class="form-title"><b>Course Drop</b>
    <div class="level-wrapper">
        <div class="info-text">{{ student.level }}</div>
    </div>
    </p>
    <div class="container">
        <form action="{% url 'course_drop' %}" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between mb-4">
                <button title="Save Score" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                    <i class="fa fa-times"></i> Drop Selected
                </button>
            </div>

            <!-- <div>
            <a target="_blank" href="{% url 'course_registration_form' %}" class="btn btn-outline-white btn-rounded btn-sm px-2">
                <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Print Registration Form
              </a>
            </div> -->

            <div class="table-responsive p-0 px-2 mt-2">
                <div class="table-shadow">
                    <table class="table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Mark</th>
                                <th>Course Code</th>
                                <th>Course Title</th>
                                <th>Cr.Hr(s)</th>
                                <th>Year</th>
                                <th>Classification</th>
                                <th>Elective Group</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            {% for course in registered_courses %}
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row">
                                    <input name="{{ course.pk }}" value="{{ course.courseUnit }}" type="checkbox">
                                </th>
                                <td>{{ course.code }}</td>
                                <td>{{ course.title }}</td>
                                <td>{{ course.credit }}</td>
                                <td>{{ course.year }}</td>
                                {% if course.is_elective %}
                                <td>Elective</td>
                                {% else %}
                                <td>Core</td>
                                {% endif %}
                                <th>-</th>
                            </tr>
                            {% empty %}
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td>
                                    <span class="text-danger">
                                        No Course.
                                    </span>
                                </td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            {% endfor %}
                            <tr>
                                <th></th>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td><b>Total credit(s):</b> {{ total_registered_credit }} </td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    <script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        document.querySelectorAll('select[name^="class_"]').forEach(function(select) {
            select.addEventListener("change", function() {
                document.getElementById(select.name + "_hidden").value = select.value;
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
    </div>
</div>

{% endif %}
{% endif %}
{% endif %}

{% endblock content %}

It should recorded two input fields, course_id and class_id. The actual result was that course_id was recorded, but class_id was not. When debugging, the variable request.POST did show a key class_id, but its value was an empty string.
